# Dot Product and Simplification

Tags: vector, dot

How to simplify the expression

`a b . x/((a b) . x)`

Where a is a scalar and b and x are vectors.

I have tried the usual Simplify, FullSimplify, TensorExpand etc. but the expression does not simplify to 1.

Answer (score 10):

You'll want to use `TensorReduce` or `TensorExpand` with appropriate assumptions for reducing expressions involving `Dot`:

```
TensorReduce[a b . x / ((a b) . x), 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, (b | x) \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]}]

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: why use `TensorReduce` function ？

Answer (score 2):

Use TensorExpand with reaonable Assumptions

```
    In[28]:= Assuming[(x | z) \[Element] Vectors[dim], 
 TensorExpand[{(a x)  \[TensorProduct] (q z ), (a x) . (q z + c  x)} ]]

Out[28]= {a q x\[TensorProduct]z, a c x . x + a q x . z}
```